# Keep getting error:app not setup the developers of this app have not set up this app properly for facebook login

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to develop an android app who use a "Facebook Login", I am working with Eclipse and downloaded the FacebookSDK.

I worked by this guide:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2

I got the message from tittle when I am trying to connect my app from my android device.
I searched dor this problem here and the solutions i found is to set 
status and review to ON in my app settings here:
https://developers.facebook.com/

after setting status and review to ON in 'Status & Review' from,
problem didn't solved and it keeps show this message.

I have tried to remove this app from my developer account on facebook and open a new one, and again - same error message:  "app not setup: the developers of this app have not set up this app properly for facebook login"

I'm hopeless..... any suggestions?!

Answer (score 1):

1.Select app.
2.Go to Status & Review.
3.Select "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?".Make this YES.